# Would Black Númenóreans be more powerful than Aragorn and the Dúnedain?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

As Númenóreans I thought they possibly would have been.  Are there any references in Tolkien's writings to support this?

Comment: More powerful in what way?? As far as I can remember the Witchking was one, so maybe, but all things being equal (leaving the Nine out of it), they would all be human, and "more powerful" comes down to better trained or more luck in a fight, which is - as you state - asking for an opinion.

Comment: What do you mean by "more powerful?" The Mouth of Sauron was a Black Numenorean.

Comment: A word of caution: if you're looking for peoples opinions you risk your question being closed as "Primarily Opinion Based".  I've edited your question in an attempt to rescue it; please feel free to roll-back this edit if it changes your intent (although I advise that doing so will probably result in it being closed).

Comment: That's racist...

Answer (score 3):

No.

The Black Númenóreans were descended from Second Age "King's Men" of Númenor, and a footnote to *Return of the King* Appendix A notes this about them:

> (Umbar) was a stronghold of the King's Men, who were afterwards called the Black Númenóreans, corrupted by Sauron, and who hated above all the followers of Elendil.

The Númenóreans who were corrupted by Sauron had fallen; they had shorter lifespans, gave up their lives unwillingly, and were even borderline insane, as the *Akallabêth* notes:

> For whereas aforetime men had grown slowly old, and had laid them down in the end to sleep, when they were weary at last of the world, now madness and sickness assailed them; and yet they were afraid to die and go out into the dark, the realm of the lord that they had taken; and they cursed themselves in their agony. And men took weapons in those days and slew one another for little cause...

The same footnote I cite in my first quote goes on to say:

> After the fall of Sauron their race swiftly dwindled or became merged with the Men of Middle-earth, but they inherited without lessening their hatred of Gondor.  Umbar, therefore, was only taken at great cost.

So any notion that the Black Númenóreans were more pure-blooded (perhaps because of the events of the Kin Strife) must be discarded: they weren't.

Comment: The "fall of Sauron" mentioned here was at the end of the Second Age, *not* the Third.

Comment: How do you get "pure blooded" out of "more powerful?"

Comment: @Lexible - The pure-bloodedness of various Men (in particular Numenoreans) is an undercurrent that flows mostly submerged in LotR.  (See, e.g., Gandalf's comment about Denethor, in RotK, "Minas Tirith": "the blood of Westernesse runs nearly true in him". Gandalf then attributes certain "powers" to Denethor as a result: "long sight," mind reading.)  The inference in this and other references in the stories is that pure-blooded Numenoreans have greater abilities.

Comment: @Rob: Doesn't Tolkien at one point say that elves and men are the same species? Pure-bloodedness might come into play if that's true.

Comment: @James Sheridan: In Letter 144 (which, oddly, I have bookmarked), Tolkien comments that Elves are similar to Men in appearance and, "if pressed to rationalize," notes that Elves "represent" Men enhanced with greater qualities and nobility.  He declines to go into the other differences, but also says that a Man's "only real claim to 'nobility'" was by having some Elvish blood.  However, I was referring more to Tolkien's general penchant for separating "greater" (e.g., Aragorn) Men from "lesser" (e.g., Eomer) Men, as well as noting their resulting relative abilities.

Comment: @Rob The implication is that pure-blooded Numenoreans have *certain* abilities, not *greater* abilities. Perhaps Black Numenoreans have *certain other* abilities: for example, they hypothetically sensing men's weaknesses of character, or persuasiveness over orcs and trolls. Just because such qualities are not mentioned in cannon does not mean that Black Numenoreans are simply "lesser" men with a cool pedigree.

Comment: @Lexible: I probably wasn't clear in expressing my thought in my earlier comment.  What I meant was that Tolkien in his works implies (and in some places states clearly) that Men who are not of noble blood (in his world, an Elvish strain or Numenorean), were "lesser Men," with shorter life span and lesser abilities.  Coupled with the explicit canon statement that Black Numenoreans "swiftly dwindled or became merged" with lesser Men, in Tolkien's world this means they were not as powerful.  Lesser = weaker in this context.

Comment: It's a reference to the Kin-strife: "the Dunedain feared that her descendants would prove the same and fall from the majesty of the Kings of Men" - and the notion that the Umbarites retain more of that "majesty".

Comment: @Rob I sincerely appreciate your perspective. I think that if the OP question was *not* about Tolkein's concept of grace or lifespan, but, say, being good at doing combat, black magic, etc. one could have a principled disagreement. But since the question is closed I will move on and thank you for your contribution.